# NestJs: Why is monorepo mode only packaging root app,

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I have a Nest project set up in monorepo mode. However, when I run yarn build, Nest only puts the root app in the `dist` folder. Here's when my project structure looks like:

```
.
└── cloud-kruser-backend
    ├── apps
    │   ├── root-app
    │   │   ├── src
    │   │   └── test
    │   └── hello
    │       ├── src
    │       └── test
    └── dist
        └── apps
            └── root-app
```

After running `yarn build` I would expect `dist` to have both `root-app` and `hello`.

Here are the relevant config files:

./nest-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/root-app/src",
  "monorepo": true,
  "root": "apps/root-app",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "webpack": true,
    "tsConfigPath": "apps/root-app/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "projects": {
    "root-app": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/root-app",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/root-app/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/root-app/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    "hello": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/hello",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/hello/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/hello/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

./apps/root-app/tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "outDir": "../../dist/apps/root-app"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "test", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

./apps/hello/tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "outDir": "../../dist/apps/hello"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "test", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nest build`, like `nest start` will inherently only run on the main app. If you need to build another app as well, you need to use `nest build <app-name>`, e.g. `nest build hello`